# How to disable source maps for React JS Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, source-maps

My react folder structure is as below

[image]

I've not used the create-react-app version. I tried using `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`. But It didn't work.

Where can I find the .map files. How can I delete those files?

I cannot find a build folder.
I've tried using the below script But It cannot work in removing source maps

```
 "scripts": {

    "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false && npm run build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Add your `webpack.config.js` to the question.

Comment: I didn't have a webpack.config.js file in my file structure

Comment: What did you use to generate the project?

Comment: I use npm run start

Comment: you can not do it because create-react-app config webpack for you, if you want to manually setup your webpack, you have to run `npm run eject` (which is not recommended for beginner)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. How can I resolve this.

Comment: @BharathPabba, for build you can enable it, I've answered it below

Answer (score 160, accepted):

just remove `&&`

```
"scripts": {    
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Comment: but when i try the above code the browser still shows the code. Thanks

Comment: are you sure that your code is this
`"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"`


not this
`"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false && react-scripts build"`

Comment: As you are new to React, i strongly advice you to gor for create-react-app option and follow the react documentation ;)

Comment: yes. I used the same. The browser still shows the same

Comment: you have to generate project with `npm run build`

Comment: if you want to run build file first you need to install serve globally ‘npm run serve -g’ and ‘serve build’, after that you can open it in browser with localhost:5000

Comment: I cannot use serve on ec2 properly. Please reply if you can help me out this Issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996232/pm2-serve-on-ec2-cannot-access-url

Comment: "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",

Worked for me!

Comment: The below answer is recommended

Comment: Doesn't work: `'GENERATE_SOURCEMAP' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @PointerNull use [`cross-env`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env): `"build": "cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"`

Comment: @Arkellys 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @B.ÖNER you have to install the module.

Comment: @Arkellys Thanks. It worked after installing using "npm install --save-dev cross-env"

Answer (score 71):

You have to create a `.env` file in your root directory (same folder as `package.json`) and set `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` on a single line.

for additional configurations, you may refer to the documentation here:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration

Comment: Correct solution with react@16.13.1

Answer (score 40):

### Solution 1

Edit your `package.json` like below:

- **Windows:**

```json
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" &&  react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
```

- **Linux:**

```json
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
```

---

### Solution 2 (Recommended)

This solution is **not** operating system dependent and works on both Linux and Windows. Just create a file called `.env` in the root path of your project and add the following line to it:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Comment: set \"... windows trick works, cheers.

Answer (score 37):

What I have tested and which is working is to add this code in your `.env.production` file or `.env` file

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Answer (score 14):

For windows cmd and create-react-app + react-scripts,

You should use **set** and close with \" YOUR_TMP_ENV_VAR \"

See example:

```
"deploy:prod:hosting": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && npm run build
```

this answer helped me:
[How to set environment variable in React JS..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888214/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-react-js)

Comment: Works for me. But I don't understand why when I use `&& set PORT=3001` it's also working but without quotes. Do you know why ? Is that because of the `_` (underscore) inside `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP`?

Comment: This is the CORRECT answer. Tested on Win10. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This works for me. Hope it helps anyone.

```
// package.json

"build": "react-scripts build",
"postbuild": "rimraf build/**/*.map"
```

This way, it will auto delete map files during build generation.

Comment: This shall work, but not reasonable to follow. Better not to create *.map than to create and remove it.

Comment: @Ponleu That's right. But I was not aware that how we can prevent that unnecessary map file so this was the solution at the moment. If you find better way then you can suggest edit, that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: But when you load the application in browser, there will be 404 error for .map files

Comment: @ShivangGupta I tested this in Chrome and Firefox and you'll only get a 404 on the source maps if you open dev tools.

Answer (score 6):

just add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` in `.env`

Answer (score 4):

Put this one in your package.json

```
   "build": "cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
```

It works on Windows and Linux...

Answer (score 3):

Solution for ejected create-react-app v2.1.3.

Go to /config/webpack.config.js directory and change the following line:

```
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
```

To:

```
const shouldUseSourceMap = false;
```

And Bob is your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

After long struggle nothing worked. Finally what worked for me is 
changing sourcemap: false in webpack.config.prod.js inside nodemodules/react-script/config
hopefully it will work for you too.