# React URLs are not Accessible

Tags: reactjs, pm2

hi i've run following command  `pm2 start process.json` on ec2 AWS.

Here is my `process.json` file

```
{
  "script": "serve",
  "env": {
    "PM2_SERVE_PATH": './build',
    "PM2_SERVE_PORT": 5000
  }
}
```

When I run the pm2 command shown above. I can access the Base URL. But when I type the Sub URLs from browser, it shows a page that contains 404 |The requested path cannot be found.

Below is my file structure

[image]

I am generating the project using `npm run build` then `pm2 start process.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found a solution to this problem.

When I use serve on `pm2` it shows 404 page whenever it didn't find a url resource. To resolve that I used `screen` on ec2.

To open a new screen type `screen`
Then in your react folder type command `serve -s build -p 5000` Now you can detach your screen using **CTRL + D**

Answer (score 0):

So the app starts up and you can access the root page? What about your routes? Are they set up properly? Are you using react-routing or something else?

This sounds like a routing issue. Does it only happen on the AWS platform?

Comment: I can access the base url. But other urls are not accessible. It shows 404 error message. I use react router. yeah it only happens on AWS Platform