# npm ERR! reminder@0.1.0 build: `CI= react-scripts build`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, build, npm-build

I have a basic reactjs app.
I want to deploy it to netlify. To deploy it on netlify, I need to build it first.
But when I run `npm run build` it throws following error.

My npm version is 6.14.8.

```
CI= react-scripts build

'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reminder@0.1.0 build: `CI= react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reminder@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amarjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-17T11_18_13_129Z-debug.log
```

Comment: just run `react-scripts build`

Answer (score 4):

please go and open the package.json
please find  `"build": "CI= react-scripts build"`
and change it to `"build": "react-scripts build"`,
then go and run npm run build again
it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Go to the package.json file and do changes in the script object from "build" :"CI= react-scripts build" to "react-scripts build" , then run the command npm run build it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `package.json` file and change the ***build: "CI= react-script build***" to ***react-script build*** and then in terminal run `npm run build`. Now it'll create a build folder in your file .