# How can i save a value into an environment variable after create it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, variables, environment-variables

I have setted this env variable in my `.env` file and i want to save a value later. I'm using React.

```
REACT_APP_ID_USERLOGGED=""
```

Then i have this fragment of code that would have to save an id.

```
process.env.REACT_APP_ID_USERLOGGED = res.config.data
```

But if a do it, i receive this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid assignment left-hand side`
**So, which is the correct way to do that or how can i solve it?**

**EDIT:** I'm trying to save the id into `REACT_APP_ID_USERLOGGED` from a React Component, not into the .env file.

Comment: How are you handling the .env file? This may have already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888214/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-react-js

Comment: I'm handling it fine i think, if i set an env variable with a value in the .env file just like: `REACT_APP_ID_USERLOGGED=value` and then print it on terminal it shows well, no errors appears. 
On the other hand, i saw the link and i believe that i can't apply nothing useful. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If your intention is to save whether the user is logged in, may i know why you want to save it to the environment variable? You could utilize localstorage to store this type of data. Or you have some specific requirement for this?

Comment: Yeah, you right. I have investigated about localStorage and that's what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the end i have done this issue from the user Id with LocalStorage, without .env file or environment variables.

**By the way,** i still dont understand why my `process.env.REACT_APP_ID_USERLOGGED = res.config.data` dont work and gives me an error. If anybody could answer this it will be great.