# why do express.static reveals all my client JS files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, static, inspect

Using the following line

```
app.use(express.static("client/build"));
```

makes landing page the React component as expected.

but when every user do inspect with google chrome it reveals all my client-source code.

is there a way to hide it or it must be like that?

My revealed code

[image: My revealed code]

Comment: Do you include source maps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984146/how-to-disable-source-maps-for-react-js-application