# How to disable source maps for Vanilla HTML/Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, obfuscation, source-maps

I have done research on how to disable source maps for React js applications using an env variable or webpack config flag.

However, how do you disable sourcemaps for vanilla html, css, and javascript files?

Comment: How do you minify these files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984146/how-to-disable-source-maps-for-react-js-application

Comment: @ChrisG that works for react apps/npm based apps, but not vanilla apps/files

Comment: @Konrad I'm not sure if that's a question for me or on top of the original question. However, I know there are packages like uglify and terser-webpack that help with minification

Comment: This is entirely dependent on how you're minifying the code, I'd expect every tool to have its own way of enabling/disabling source maps.